# What are these little crystals in my Cheese?

Tags: cheese

In some Mature Cheddar, whilst slicing with a knife, I've noticed some tiny crystals.

What are these crystals are they a sign of good Cheddar or not?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To quote *On Food and Cooking* (Harold McGee), page 63, about **crystals in Cheddar:**

> In aged Cheddar, there are often
>   crystals of calcium lactate, formed
>   when ripening bacteria convert the
>   usual form of lactic acid into its
>   less soluble mirror ("D") image.

**In blue cheeses:**

> The white crystals often visible
>   against the blue mold of a Roquefort,
>   or detectable in the rind of a
>   Camembert, are calcium phosphate,
>   deposited because the *Penicillium*
>   molds have made the cheese less acid,
>   and calcium salts less soluble.

**And, in other aged cheeses:**

> In Parmesan, Gruyere, and aged Gouda,
>   the crystals may be calcium lactate or
>   else tyrosine, an amino acid produced
>   by protein breakdown that has limited
>   solubility in these low-moisture
>   cheeses.

So, basically there are a variety of salts present in the milk, and formed from milk by the action of bacteria and molds.  As the cheese dries, and ripening micro-organisms act on the cheese, these salts fall out of the solution and crystallize.  Personally, I love the slight crystalline texture present in aged cheeses, as it almost always comes with a robust and mature flavor.